# Firefox kicks table to the right

Tags: html, css, firefox

Hopefully I can explain this clearly enough. I have a table that displays some images. The table is generated dynamically with PHP. In every browser the table render correctly and in the center of the page. In firefox the table gets pushed to the right almost out of the page entirely and the scroll bar shows at the bottom of the page but it's behind elements.

This is the CSS for the table, don't know if that will help.

```
/* Portfolio Table Styles */

table {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table td {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-spacing: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

table div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table img {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -50px;
    height: 300px;

}
```

Hopefully this clears it up. This is the way it looks in firefox 7.0.1.
[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJj5B/1/)

Also, if you comment out the overflow-x at the bottom of the css it fixes it there. But in firefox that makes no difference.

Comment: Please setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: Looks fine to me (centered, not right off the screen) in FF5.

Comment: Looks fine to me as well. Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#portContent {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden
    clear: both; /*add this line*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJj5B/4/

Comment: This answer worked for me for a kind of related problem, if you're still around, would you mind telling me if you know the reason for this to happen on Firefox and not on Chrome?

Comment: for Chrome you need it too (os x). there are good articles about floats and problems with them: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I had a table push the entire header out only on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE were fine. Thanks for the link and the answer